# How to execute second function without effecting first function in PHP?

Tags: php

As the title says I want to execute second function after first function is executed. In other words, if user clicks 'Draw First number' button, a random number from 1-10 will be displayed along with a 'Draw Second number' button and then if user clicks 'Draw Second number' button, another random number from 1-10 will be displayed.

I have tried the following code but when I click 'Draw Second Number' button, it returns me to the start of the process.

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['firstnumber'])) {

   function roll () {
       return mt_rand(1,10);
   }

   echo 'First Number: '.roll().'<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Draw second number" name="secondnumber"></form>';

   if (isset($_POST['secondnumber'])) {
   echo 'Second Number: '.roll();
   }
   }

   ?>
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Draw first number" name="firstnumber">
</form>
```

I expect code to display second number when 'Second Number' button is clicked rather than going to initial code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What is the purpose of your code? (It sound like it would be better to do this in javascript) But no matter what you don't have to define function roll() twice.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your file you check the following condition

```
   <?php if (isset($_POST['firstnumber'])) {
```

So everything inside this if statement will only execute if the statements evaluates true.

If you are submitting your hardcoded HTML Formular (the "firstnumber" one). The If statement evaluates true, thus the code inside it gets run.

Inside the If Statement you call your previously defined function `roll();` and you echo out another formular.

This formular (the "secondnumber" one) is only echo'd out if the above  if statement is evaluated true.

If you now submit your second formular (the "secondnumber" one) the if statement at the top evaluates **false**, because then the field `firstnumber` in **$_POST** is **not** set!

Why isn't it set? Because you just submitted a formular (the "secondnumber" one) which doesn't have any field named `firstnumber`.

Try the following code:

```
<?php

   function roll() {
       return mt_rand(1,10);
   }

   if (isset($_POST['firstnumber']) === true || isset($_POST['secondnumber']) === true) {
       if (isset($_POST['firstnumber'])) {
           echo 'First Number: ' . roll() . '<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Draw second number" name="secondnumber"></form>';
       }

       if (isset($_POST['secondnumber'])) {
           $secondNumber = roll();
       }
   }
   ?>
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Draw first number" name="firstnumber">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it does exactly what I was looking for. Just I would like to add one thing: When I click 'Draw Second Number', is it possible to display 'First Number' as well? For example, on clicking 'Draw First Number', first number appear as 7. Then clicking 'Draw Second Number', 7 again display with second number.

Comment: Yes, of course it would be possible. But since "first Number" isn't saved anywhere, you can't access it when you generate your second number. There are a few ways you could save the first number:  Save it in the Session (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), set it as the value of a hidden field or even save it in a database. Try what you like, since it is only for learning purpose